# Is there a generalization of Furstenberg theorem from SL(2,R) to SL(2,C) matrices?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I learnt from a talk that consider a random product of i.i.d. matrices, randomly chosen from SL(2,R): $T_n=A_n \cdots A_2 A_1$, where the random matrices $A_i$ are i.i.d.

A classical Furstenberg theorem then implies, that under some very mild nondegeneracy conditions (no finite common invariant set of lines, no common invariant metric) for the law of $A_i$'s the norm of such a product almost surely grows exponentially.

Now I wonder if this conclusion also holds if the matrices are chosen from SL(2,C)?

For simplicity, I checked the case with two matrices $A=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}i &0\\0 &-i\end{array}\right]$ and $B=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}1+i &-i\\i &1-i\end{array}\right]$. Now I multiply the matrices which are randomly chosen from $A$ and $B$ with probability $1/2$ and $1/2$, and find that indeed the norm of such a product grows exponentially. But I am not sure if there is a proof for this. Thanks!

Comment: I think Goldsheid and Margulis priced this in much greater generality.

Comment: Yes - the argument of Furstenberg actually applies to any real rank 1 situation (in particular, to $Sl(2,\mathbb C)$). The "much greater" generality mentioned by Misha refers to a somewhat different question about simplicity of the Lyapunov spectrum.

Comment: hi R W, thanks for your answer. I wonder if you can recommend a relevant reference? That would help very much, thanks!

Comment: Read [this book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/lectures-on-lyapunov-exponents/42E4EAB1756EA3248148F48E2CD89813)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original work of Furstenberg "Non-commuting random products" (1963) actually contains an answer to your question in Theorem 8.6 which states the positivity of the top Lyapunov exponent for **any** random walk on $SL(d,\mathbb R)$ under the natural first moment condition and the irreducibility condition your mention. So in your case you just have to embed $SL(2,\mathbb C)$ into a higher order real matrix group.

Comment: I think you meant strong irreduciability not irreducibility. For instance, consider Kifer's example $A_{1}=diag(2, 1/2)$, $A_{2}=antidiag(1, 1)$ .